# archivo cargado temporal no se envía a la carpeta especificada

Tags: php, sql, pdo, crud

¡Buenas, chicos y chicas!

Realmente no encuentro la solución al problema. Estoy aprendiendo PHP y este es uno de mis primeros CRUD.

Quiero: Crear categoría($cat_name) con descripción($cat_desc) y imagen($cat_img)

El problema viene cuando quiero guardar la imagen, ya que no la guarda en la carpeta "uploads", pero si todos los datos en la base de datos

Por favor, si alguien podría ayudar, seria de gran ayuda ;)

PHP >>>>

```
    if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    $img = $_FILES['cat_name'];
    $imgName = $img['name'];
    $imgTmpName = $img['tmp_name'];
    $imgSize = $img['size'];
    $imgError = $img['error'];
    $imgType = $img['type'];

    $cat_name = $_POST["cat_name"];
    $cat_desc = $_POST["cat_desc"];


    //revisamos si hay errores
    if (empty($cat_name)) {
        $cat_name_err = "Пожалуйста, введите имя категории.";
    } elseif (!filter_var($cat_name, FILTER_VALIDATE_REGEXP, array("options" => array("regexp" => "/^[a-zA-Z\sаАбБвВгГдДеЕёЁжЖзЗиИйЙкКлЛмМнНоОпПрРсСтТуУфФхХцЦчЧшШщЩъЪыЫьЬэЭюЮяЯ1234567890]+$/")))) {
        $cat_name_err = "Пожалуйста, используйте только буквы и цифры.";
    } elseif (empty($cat_desc)) {
        $cat_desc_err = "Пожалуйста, введите описание категории.";
    } else {
        $sql = "SELECT id FROM cats WHERE cat_name = :cat_name";
        $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->bindParam(":cat_name", $cat_name, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->execute();
        if ($stmt->rowCount() > 0) {
            $cat_name_err = "Данная категория уже сущиствует.";
        } else {

            //adaptamos la extencion del archivo cargado
            $imgOldExt = explode('.', $imgName);
            $imgExt = strtolower(end($imgOldExt));
            //archivos permetidos
            $allowed = array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'pdf');

            if (in_array($imgExt, $allowed)) {
                // revisamos si hay errores
                if ($imgError === 0) {
                    // revisamos el tamaño del archivo
                    if ($imgSize < 1000000) {
                        // creamos el nombre de archivo
                        $cat_img = $cat_name . "." . $imgExt;
                        // generamos PATH para archivos 
                        $imgDestination = 'uploads/' . $cat_img;
                        // cargamos archivo al la carpeta UPLOADS
                        move_uploaded_file($imgTmpName, $imgDestination);


                        $sql = "INSERT INTO `cats` (`id`, `cat_name`, `cat_desc`, `cat_img`) VALUES (NULL, :cat_name, :cat_desc, :cat_img );";
                        if ($stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql)) {
                            
                            $stmt->bindParam(":cat_name", $param_cat_name);
                            $stmt->bindParam(":cat_desc", $param_cat_desc);
                            $stmt->bindParam(":cat_img", $param_cat_img);

                            $param_cat_name = $cat_name;
                            $param_cat_desc = $cat_desc;
                            $param_cat_img = $cat_img;

                            if ($stmt->execute()) {
                                session_start();
                                // Si todo bien...Creamos mensaje y redirigimos a la pagina de inicio
                                $_SESSION["msg"] = "Категория создана!";
                                header("location: index.php");
                                exit();
                            } else {
                                session_start();
                                $_SESSION["msg"] = "Algo no va bien.";
                            }
                        }
                    } else {
                        $cat_img_err = "Размер архива очень большой!";
                    }
                } else {
                    $cat_img_err  = "Совершенна ошибка отправкиб пожалуйста попробуйте снова";
                }
            } else {
                $cat_img_err =  "Этот формат не поддерживается, пожалуйста, пользуйтесь форматами JPG, JPEG, PNG, PDF!";
            }

            // Close statement
            unset($stmt);
            // Close connection
            unset($pdo);

        }
    }
}
```

HTML >>>>

```
<form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>cat_name</label>
                        <input type="text" name="cat_name" class="form-control <?php echo (!empty($cat_name_err)) ? 'is-invalid' : ''; ?>" value="<?php echo $cat_name; ?>">
                        <span class="invalid-feedback"><?php echo $cat_name_err; ?></span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>cat_desc</label>
                        <textarea name="cat_desc" class="form-control <?php echo (!empty($cat_desc_err)) ? 'is-invalid' : ''; ?>"><?php echo $cat_desc; ?></textarea>
                        <span class="invalid-feedback"><?php echo $cat_desc_err; ?></span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>cat_img</label>
                        <input type="file" name="cat_img" class="form-control <?php echo (!empty($cat_img_err)) ? 'is-invalid' : ''; ?>" value="<?php echo $cat_img; ?>">
                        <span class="invalid-feedback"><?php echo $cat_img_err; ?></span>
                    </div>
                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit" name="submit">
                    <a href="index.php" class="btn btn-secondary ml-2">Cancel</a>
                </form>
```

SQL >>>

```
create table cat (
    id int(11) AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    cat_name VARCHAR(100) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
    cat_desc VARCHAR(600) NOT NULL,
    cat_img VARCHAR(256) NOT NULL
);
```

PD: Variables de errores están en ruso jejeje y no pienso que será el problema no? Muchísimas gracias por vuestro tiempo :)

Comment: no estas pasando al reves los parametros? que yo sepa, cuando pasas un parametro, no se queda con el nombre de la variable, si no con el contenido... puede que php funcione diferente.. pero yo invertiria el orden... de paso, te fijaste que todas las variables tuvieran valor?

Comment: Gracias @gbianchi, en el input de carga de imagen indiqué el nombre `"cat_name"` y lo quería recibir con nombre `"file"`. Pero me sigue faltando medio error... que es que archivo temporal no se mueve a la carpeta indicada

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**RESUELTO**

Efectivamente, me he liado con parámetros al haber copiado parte de código del trabajo anterior :)

Público, como lo arregle por si podéis comentarlo o veis algo que se puede mejorar ;)

```
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    $img = $_FILES['cat_img'];
    $imgName = $img['name'];
    $imgTmpName = $img['tmp_name'];
    $imgSize = $img['size'];
    $imgError = $img['error'];
    $imgType = $img['type'];

    $cat_name = $_POST["cat_name"];
    $cat_desc = $_POST["cat_desc"];

    //  adaptamos la extencion del archivo cargado
    $imgOldExt = explode('.', $imgName);
    $imgExt = strtolower(end($imgOldExt));
    //archivos permetidos
    $allowed = array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'pdf');
    if (!in_array($imgExt, $allowed)) {
        $cat_img_err = "Formato no permetido";
    } elseif ($imgError > 0) {
        echo $imgError;
        $cat_img_err = "problemas con la carga";
    } elseif ($imgSize > 1000000) {
        $cat_img_err = "Imagen demarciado grande" . byteToMb($imgSize);
    } elseif (empty($cat_name)) {
        $cat_name_err = "Пожалуйста, введите имя категории.";
    } elseif (!filter_var($cat_name, FILTER_VALIDATE_REGEXP, array("options" => array("regexp" => "/^[a-zA-Z\sаАбБвВгГдДеЕёЁжЖзЗиИйЙкКлЛмМнНоОпПрРсСтТуУфФхХцЦчЧшШщЩъЪыЫьЬэЭюЮяЯ1234567890]+$/")))) {
        $cat_name_err = "Пожалуйста, используйте только буквы и цифры.";
    } elseif (empty($cat_desc)) {
        $cat_desc_err = "Пожалуйста, введите описание категории.";
    } else {
        $sql = "SELECT id FROM cats WHERE cat_name = :cat_name";
        $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->bindParam(":cat_name", $cat_name, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->execute();
        if ($stmt->rowCount() > 0) {
            $cat_name_err = "Данная категория уже сущиствует.";
        } else {
            $cat_img = $cat_name . "." . $imgExt;
            // creamos PATH para archivos 
            $imgDestination = 'uploads/' . $cat_img;
            // cargamos archivo al la carpeta UPLOADS
            move_uploaded_file($imgTmpName, $imgDestination);

            $sql = "INSERT INTO `cats` (`id`, `cat_name`, `cat_desc`, `cat_img`) VALUES (NULL, :cat_name, :cat_desc, :cat_img );";
            if ($stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql)) {
                $stmt->bindParam(":cat_name", $param_cat_name);
                $stmt->bindParam(":cat_desc", $param_cat_desc);
                $stmt->bindParam(":cat_img", $param_cat_img);

                $param_cat_name = $cat_name;
                $param_cat_desc = $cat_desc;
                $param_cat_img = $cat_img;

                if ($stmt->execute()) {
                    session_start();
                    // Si todo bien...Creamos mensaje y redirigimos a la pagina de inicio
                    $_SESSION["msg"] = "Категория создана!";
                    header("location: index.php");
                    exit();
                } else {
                    session_start();
                    $_SESSION["msg"] = "Algo no va bien, intentalo de nuevo o pongase en contacto con nosotros.";
                }
            }

            // Close statement
            unset($stmt);
            // Close connection
            unset($pdo);
        }
    }
}
```

*Moraleja: Es mejor escribir que copiar ;)*